# ¿Como soluciono este error cuando realizo un crud en spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Tengo un problema cuando hago click en actualizar me aparece una ventana y alli actualizo los datos pero en vez de actualizar me crea otro registro no se a que se debe a continuacion dejo el código:

Model

clase usuario

@Entity
public class Usuario extends AbstractPersistable {

```
private transient Long id;

private String usuarioId;

private String usuarioNombre;

private String clave;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="rol_id")
private Rol rol;


@OneToMany(targetEntity=Direccion.class, mappedBy="usuario", fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Direccion> direcciones;



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsuarioId() {
    return usuarioId;
}

public void setUsuarioId(String usuarioId) {
    this.usuarioId = usuarioId;
}

public String getUsuarioNombre() {
    return usuarioNombre;
}

public void setUsuarioNombre(String usuarioNombre) {
    this.usuarioNombre = usuarioNombre;
}

public String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}

public Rol getRol() {
    return rol;
}

public void setRol(Rol rol) {
    this.rol = rol;
}

en la clase direccion
```

@Entity
public class Direccion extends AbstractPersistable{

```
private String ciudad;
private String distrito;
private String pais;

private transient Long usuarioId;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="usuario_id")
private Usuario usuario;




public Long getUsuarioId() {
    return usuarioId;
}
public void setUsuarioId(Long usuarioId) {
    this.usuarioId = usuarioId;
}
public String getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}
public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}
public String getDistrito() {
    return distrito;
}
public void setDistrito(String distrito) {
    this.distrito = distrito;
}
public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}
public void setPais(String pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
```

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/direccion")
@Controller
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true,securedEnabled = true, 
jsr250Enabled = true)
public class DireccionController {


    private DireccionService direccionService;

    private UsuarioService usuarioService;


    public DireccionController(DireccionService direccionService,UsuarioService usuarioService) {

        this.direccionService = direccionService;
        this.usuarioService=usuarioService;
    }



    @GetMapping("/actualizar/{id}")
    public String actualizarDireccion(@PathVariable Long id,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("direccion",direccionService.getDireccion(id));
        model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.getUsuario(id));
        model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.usuarioLista());
        return "direccion/lista";
    }


    @GetMapping("/lista")
    public String direccionLista(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
        model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.usuarioLista());
        return "direccion/lista";

    }

    @GetMapping("/lista/{id}")
    public Optional<Direccion> getDireccion(@PathVariable Long id){
        return direccionService.getDireccion(id);

    }


    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
    public String agregarDireccion(@ModelAttribute("direcciones") Direccion direcciones,Model model)throws IOException {

        model.addAttribute("direcciones", direccionService.agregarDireccion(direcciones).getUsuario().getUsuarioNombre());
        return "redirect:/direccion/lista";

    }

    @GetMapping("/eliminar/{id}")
    public String eliminarDireccion(@PathVariable  Long id,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("mensaje",direccionService.eliminarDireccion(id));
        return "redirect:/direccion/lista";

    }   
}
```

### JSP

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
         <button  class="btn btn-primary nBtn" >Nuevo</button>
          <br>
          <br>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Ciudad</th>
                <th>Distrito</th>
                <th>Pais</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Actualizar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>   
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${direcciones}" var="direccion">
                <tr>
                    <td>${direccion.id}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.ciudad}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.distrito}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.pais}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.usuario.usuarioNombre}</td>
                    <td><a href="${path}/direccion/actualizar/${direccion.id}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Actualizar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="${path}/direccion/eliminar/${direccion.id}"  class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>

            </c:forEach>

        </tbody>



    </table>
    </div>
    </div>

  <div class="myForm">

    <form:form  action="${path}/direccion/agregar" method="post"  modelAttribute="<direcciones>,<usuarios>" >

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" 
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar o Guardar</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id" class="col-form-label">Codigo:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value=""/>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pais" class="col-form-label">Pais:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pais" name="pais" value=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Ciudad:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad"  value=""/>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="distrito" class="col-form-label">Distrito:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distrito" name="distrito" value=""/>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="usuario" class="col-form-label">Usuario:</label>

                        <select name="usuario.id" id="usuario" required>
                            <c:forEach items="${usuarios}" var="usuario" >

                                <option value="${usuario.id}">${usuario.usuarioNombre}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>   
                    </div>



             </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="guardar"/>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        </form:form>
      </div>    


</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.nBtn, .table .eBtn').on('click',function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var href=$(this).attr('href');
        var text=$(this).text();

        if(text=='Actualizar' ){ 


        $.get(href,function(direccion,usuario,status){
            $('.myForm #id').val(direccion.id);
            $('.myForm #ciudad').val(direccion.ciudad);
            $('.myForm #distrito').val(direccion.distrito);
            $('.myForm #pais').val(direccion.ciudad);
            $('.myForm #usuario').val(direccion.usuario);
        });

        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();

    }else{

        $('.myForm #id').val('');
        $('.myForm #ciudad').val('');
        $('.myForm #distrito').val('');
        $('.myForm #pais').val('');
        $('.myForm #usuario').val('');

        $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
    }

    });
});
```

salida:

Hibernate: select direccion0_.id as id1_0_0_, direccion0_.ciudad as ciudad2_0_0_, direccion0_.distrito as distrito3_0_0_, direccion0_.pais as pais4_0_0_, direccion0_.usuario_id as usuario_5_0_0_, usuario1_.id as id1_3_1_, usuario1_.clave as clave2_3_1_, usuario1_.rol_id as rol_id5_3_1_, usuario1_.usuario_id as usuario_3_3_1_, usuario1_.usuario_nombre as usuario_4_3_1_, rol2_.id as id1_2_2_, rol2_.nombre as nombre2_2_2_ from direccion direccion0_ left outer join usuario usuario1_ on direccion0_.usuario_id=usuario1_.id left outer join rol rol2_ on usuario1_.rol_id=rol2_.id where direccion0_.id=?
Hibernate: select usuario0_.id as id1_3_, usuario0_.clave as clave2_3_, usuario0_.rol_id as rol_id5_3_, usuario0_.usuario_id as usuario_3_3_, usuario0_.usuario_nombre as usuario_4_3_ from usuario usuario0_
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into direccion (ciudad, distrito, pais, usuario_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select usuario0_.id as id1_3_0_, usuario0_.clave as clave2_3_0_, usuario0_.rol_id as rol_id5_3_0_, usuario0_.usuario_id as usuario_3_3_0_, usuario0_.usuario_nombre as usuario_4_3_0_, rol1_.id as id1_2_1_, rol1_.nombre as nombre2_2_1_ from usuario usuario0_ left outer join rol rol1_ on usuario0_.rol_id=rol1_.id where usuario0_.id=?
Hibernate: select direccion0_.id as id1_0_, direccion0_.ciudad as ciudad2_0_, direccion0_.distrito as distrito3_0_, direccion0_.pais as pais4_0_, direccion0_.usuario_id as usuario_5_0_ from direccion direccion0_
Hibernate: select usuario0_.id as id1_3_0_, usuario0_.clave as clave2_3_0_, usuario0_.rol_id as rol_id5_3_0_, usuario0_.usuario_id as usuario_3_3_0_, usuario0_.usuario_nombre as usuario_4_3_0_, rol1_.id as id1_2_1_, rol1_.nombre as nombre2_2_1_ from usuario usuario0_ left outer join rol rol1_ on usuario0_.rol_id=rol1_.id where usuario0_.id=?
Hibernate: select usuario0_.id as id1_3_, usuario0_.clave as clave2_3_, usuario0_.rol_id as rol_id5_3_, usuario0_.usuario_id as usuario_3_3_, usuario0_.usuario_nombre as usuario_4_3_ from usuario usuario0_

Comment: Revisa que estés recibiendo el `ID` del campo que quieres actualizar a través del formulario. Me suena un poco a que no se está pasando por el POST.

Comment: @Libra2880 debes usar put para actualizar los datos @PutMapping("/asd/asd")

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Lo que intentas actualizar son solo las direcciones que puede tener un usuario? O ¿Estás actualizando también información del usuario?

Comment: solo direcciones que pueden tener un usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya me salio el botón actualizar y agregar

En el Model tenia que cambiar el siguiente código:

@Entity
public class Direccion{

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private transient Long usuarioId;

private String ciudad;
private String distrito;
private String pais;




public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="usuario_id")
private Usuario usuario;




public Long getUsuarioId() {
    return usuarioId;
}
public void setUsuarioId(Long usuarioId) {
    this.usuarioId = usuarioId;
}
public String getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}
public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}
public String getDistrito() {
    return distrito;
}
public void setDistrito(String distrito) {
    this.distrito = distrito;
}
public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}
public void setPais(String pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso tienes que asegurarte que el @PostMapping("/agregar") recibe correctamente el objeto que quieres guardar y que este tenga pre-establecido un ID cuando sea el caso de actualizar, te paso un ejemplo simple que funciona:

Nota: previamente has tenido que cargar en un formulario todo lo relacionado en tu caso con la dirección y su usuario para que cuando des click en guardar puedas llamar a esta función desde la vista.

```
    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    public String agregar(@Valid Cliente cliente, Model model) {

        String debug= (cliente.getId() != null)? "Cliente editado con éxito!" : "Cliente creado con éxito!";

        clienteService.save(cliente); //Crea o actualiza automaticamente

        return "listar";
    }
```

Es el mismo método tanto para actualizar que para añadir por lo que depende del id de usuario.

```
public interface IClienteService {
    public void save(Cliente cliente);
}
```

Tendrás en la implementación del `IClienteService` la siguiente función:

```
@Service
public class ClienteServiceImpl implements IClienteService{
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Cliente cliente) {
        clienteDao.save(cliente);
    }
}
```

Y el DAO será de la siguiente manera, muy muy simple:

```
public interface IClienteDao extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long> {}
```

Una vez actualizado solo tendrás que redirigir a la vista donde realizas el listado del objeto que acabas de actualizar.

Un saludo.

Comment: Voy a revisar gracias pero tengo en mi proyecto una clase medida que allí si me actualiza. Pero en este problema hay dos clases relacionadas la clase Dirección y Usuario

Comment: Por lo que veo es que tienes la clase Direccion y esta tiene un atributo usuario del tipo Usuario, por lo que si tu guardas con save() la dirección se debería de guardar el usuario también, solo preocupate de que esté bien puesto el MAPEO JPA y que tengas un `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` en el mismo.